# mac 版の VSCode でショートカットのみでファイルパスをコピーするには？

Tags: macos, vscode

mac 版の VSCode にて、アクティブなファイルのパスをコピーするショートカットはあるでしょうか？

Windows なら以下のショートカットを使用できるのですが、

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>（コンテキストメニュー表示）
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>（パスコピー）

mac のコンテキストメニュー表示にパスコピーの項目はなく、コンテキストメニュー表示させてパスコピーショートカットを押してもコピーできないです。

解決方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0):

調べたらありました笑
mac
command k p
windows
ctr k p